# How do i add 1 more column to this score sheet PIC attached of what i was expecting All the maths is good just need to duplicate

Tags: flutter, listview, row, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I have made 1 scoring sheet, but we have 2 rounds so I need x 2 next to each other I was looking at cells and columns, but not sure what to use or how to implement them into the code.

Code and screenshot of what I'm after - thanks all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf9mE.png)

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Twin City Bowmen Score Sheet';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController num1controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num2controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num3controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num4controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num5controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num6controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num7controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num8controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num9controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num10controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num11controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num12controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num13controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num14controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num15controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num16controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num17controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num18controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num19controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num20controller = new TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 1:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num1controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 2:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num2controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 3:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num3controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 4:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num4controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 5:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num5controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 6:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num6controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 7:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num8controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 8:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num9controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 9:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num10controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 10:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num11controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 11:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num12controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 12:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num13controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 13:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num14controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 14:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num15controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 15:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num16controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 16:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num17controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 17:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num18controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 18:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num19controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 19:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num20controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Target 20:"),
                new Flexible(
                  child: new TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: num7controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      int sum = int.parse(num1controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num2controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num3controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num4controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num5controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num6controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num7controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num8controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num9controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num10controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num11controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num12controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num13controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num14controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num15controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num16controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num17controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num18controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num19controller.text) +
                          int.parse(num20controller.text);
                      result = sum.toString();
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Result:",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  result,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried the above with cells and columns but I just get to many errors to work out where I'm going wrong sorry for the newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you just need a row and column and putting all the textfields and title will do your job.

Rather i have made you some improvements as used a list of `TextEditingController` rather sepreate variables and `ListView.builders` rather than taking a separate text and textfield 20 times.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTwoNumbers> createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  List<TextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
  List<TextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
  int roundOneResult = 0;
  int roundTwoResult = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    roundOneFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    roundTwoFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundOneFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                          roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                      roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                          roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pixel, your comments " just need a row and column " make sense but when i tried the code it had some issues with Classes and naming Im writing in dart/Flutter was that code for Flutter thanks. Sorry or did you have a chance to compile it, again much appreaciated for any help

Comment: I didn't fully understood what you are saying, But the code above is complete you just need to replace it with your `AddTwoNumbers` class and it will work. I do have told you the " just need a row and column" will work but it will be too lengthy, i have made you some improvements and got the results use it and try to understand it. Happy Learning!

Comment: I tried your code in the debugger and i came out with errors so is there anything i need to do on my side sorry im confused as well. When you say repace it with your AddTwoNumbers class do you mean you have aready written that inthe code or i need too. Sorry about the confusion and thanks again for your reply Pixel

Comment: See you `main()` function and `MyApp` class will be as it is and remove all code below and put my code there. done!

Comment: Hi Pixel had issues with the expand class:
      ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
            ).expand(),
    error:
The method 'expand' isn't defined for the type 'ListView'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'expand'

Comment: Ohh i'm sorry, that's a extension. You can just remove `.expand()` and wrap both the `ListView.builders` with `Expanded` widget thats it. tell be you're unable to do it.

Comment: HI Pixel i gave it a go and could not wrap Expanded around Listview just errored out. Can you please show me the syntax thanks

Comment: HI Pixel, i ran what you posted but came up with a black screen after i debugged it sorry, does it debug ok on your Flutter complier thanks

Comment: Yeah it works fine at my end. Let me edit my answer this time you just take the code from the answer and replace it with your full main file code.

Comment: Thanks so much for being patient with me, you have have taught me much, it worked well thanks. Complied perficly